# how can i make a front end such that it takes the input performs calculations in python and returns the result to html

Tags: python, frontend

I have a machine learning model which is trained to perform classification. I want to provide the test data through a front end(I have web based front end in my mind if there is any other option then please recommend.). So i would require an html page to take the input , pass it to the backend so that calculations can be performed in python and return it back to the html page. How can i do this?

[EDIT] I started with django. I am able to render the html page but how do i pass the data to a python file?

Comment: Flask is a popular web app tool for python

Comment: I would use Django

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you can implement an front end for python but probably the two easiest are:

1. Using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) which is an easy to learn web microframework for python.
2. Using the [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) Web Framework which is harder to learn than Flask but provides more functionality.